# Cassandra : map map<text, text> datatype of UDT to SortedDictionary in .Net

Tags: .net, cassandra, cassandra-2.1, sorteddictionary, datastax-csharp-driver

I am using cassandra DB for .Net.
I have created a datatype `dictionary_type_property map<text,text>` inside user defined datatype, but facing problem while converting this datatype value to .Net dictionary type using udtMap.

```
.Map(s => s.MyDictionaryTypeProperty, "dictionary_type_property");
```

dictionary type property is:

```
public SortedDictionary<string, string> MyDictionaryTypeProperty { get; set; }
```

Here I am getting the below exception:
"No converter is available from Type System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[System.String,System.String] is not convertible to type System.Collections.Generic.SortedDictionary`2[System.String,System.String]"

Appreciate your help.

Comment: A friendly note on how to ask good questions. The general guidance is that you (a) provide a good summary of the problem that includes software/component versions, the full error message + full stack trace; (b) describe what you've tried to fix the problem, details of investigation you've done; and (c) minimal sample code that replicates the problem. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as the error says, you are trying to convert an IDictionary variable to SortedDictionary. However, IDictionary does not inherit from SortedDictionary, it's the other way around. I suggest you to read about inheritance, if you never heard about.

What I can suggest you, is to change

```
public SortedDictionary<string, string> MyDictionaryTypeProperty { get; set; }
```

to

```
public IDictionary<string, string> MyDictionaryTypeProperty { get; set; }
```

so this way,the method will try to "fit" an IDictionary value into a variable with the same type.

```
.Map(s => s.MyDictionaryTypeProperty, "dictionary_type_property");
```

if later you want to try to use this variable as a SortedDictionary, you might try using a cast `(SortedDictionary) MyDictionaryTypeProperty`

or

```
    SortedDictionary<string, string> sortedDictionary = new SortedDictionary<string, string>(MyDictionaryTypeProperty);
```